# How to install Ubuntu on Red Hat with KVM

Tags: redhat, ubuntu-14.04

I need to install Ubuntu Server on RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) Server 6.5. I went with the KVM route until I realised that Ubuntu isn't listed as a supported "guest" Operating System (https://access.redhat.com/articles/973133).

I'm really stumped as the solution I need to install specifically requires Ubuntu. The RHEL server is already in production and I just want to run the Ubuntu on top of this. What are my options here?

**Edit:**

I've considered Docker, but requires RHEL 7. VirtualBox isn't recommended for production by this communnity ([Is virtualbox good for live server virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/281189/is-virtualbox-good-for-live-server-virtualization)). Sure there should be a production ready environment for this, isn't there?

Comment: You install it the same way as every other operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Ubuntu on RHEL KVM even if it is not listed in the article. Every modern Linux distribution (Ubuntu-14 included) have KVM drivers built in, so the performance is gonna be good.
A OS not being on this list just means that if you need official RHEL support, you won't get it.

Comment: Thank you v. much @Daniel. Are you able to point me on how I can go about this, like some kind of tutorial as the trouble finding one on google led me to believe I couldn't achieve the installation.

Comment: You can download Ubuntu KVM ready images here: https://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04/release/ . If you never installed a VM using kvm, I recommend the Redhat official articles https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Getting_Started_Guide/index.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I've upvoted your answer, should show once my reputation grows.